# Creating a ROS msg

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried this tutorial of ROS for creating messages in order to communicate with the nodes.
I am using ubuntu 12.04 ver and ROS Hydro for this.

The error what i am getting is that i am not able to catkin_make it. It gives some error regarding the make file already installed in ros directory of linux in the folder and i am not able to generate the source file or anything.

Any feedback regarding this is welcomed...

thnks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149501/creating-a-ros-msg/) by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-04-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-04-07**:
Please give more details of what you are doing and of the error you get.

**Comment by [sonny](https://answers.ros.org/users/13381/sonny/) on 2014-04-07**:
I am getting an error smthing like this,

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:85 (message):
add_message_files() directory not found:
/home/traininghes/catkin_ws/src/hrsl/msg
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hrsl/CMakeLists.txt:48 (add_message_files)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Invoking "cmake" failed

**Comment by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) on 2014-04-07**:
Please edit also your question posting your CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the ros setup script has not been previosuly executed:

> $ source /opt/ros/XXX/setup.bash

where xxx is the ros distro name, ie: hydro, jade, etc...

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0